# What should I do if a user begins to missuse the site

Tags: discussion

I see that a user has begun to behave strangely and is posting inaccurate and unkind comments. And is also down voting answers that is fully correct.

Please advice.

Answer (score 7):

> I see that a user has begun to behave strangely and is posting inaccurate and unkind comments.

WRT "unkind", please flag these and they will be deleted if there is reasonable grounds.  That doesn't include someone curtly contradicting you, etc., but it does include personal attacks ("you always do this [perceived negative activity]"), insults, and belittlement.

Occasionally (maybe a few times a year) someone goes overboard with this and we (I or one of the other mods) can send them private warnings or suspend their privileges for a short time.  This *usually* solves the problem.

Flagging is critical, because I don't read every single comment.  When in doubt, flag.  If the mod who handles it disagrees, you'll get declined with a brief explanation.

WRT "inaccurate", that is more like the following.

> is also down voting answers that is fully correct

Since voting is private, this presumes that person has told you s/he has downvoted something.  In this case, there will be a comment that can be flagged.

If it is just a presumption and you don't know for sure, the site does have an automated system to catch "revenge downvoting", ie., when someone goes and downvotes a bunch of your posts in a given time period.

Beyond that, "fully correct" is always subject to personal judgement. It would be nice if everyone, or at least the first one or two, downvoters included an explanation, but for better or worse the system does not require this.

Comment: Thx for the answer.